# MySQL - Select Month difference

Tags: mysql, date, select, datediff

So I can get the days with `SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),expires)` but not exactly a month with an output of one (1). Isn't this anyhow possible to transform it to month in MySQL? I want to check if a given date (like `expires`) is >= 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   ...
FROM
   tablename
WHERE
   expires<=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Will get you all rows, that have expired a month ago or earlier

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
  Select * from 
  table_name where TIMESTAMPDIFF
  (MONTH, 
  ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1),
  ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1)
  )>=1
```